# ListAdapter in preferences?

Tags: android, preferences, listadapter

Is there a way to use ListAdapter in preferences screen ?
or i must use only chekboxpreference, textpreferences, etc....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own custom `DialogPreference` that uses a `ListView` with your custom `ListAdapter`.